# Which steps is good to have in.Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

I use Jenkins to my project as my CI system.

At this moment I have this steps

- Download code from git
- Download missing nuget packages
- Compile and publish my main project
- Run unit tests
- Run visual tests (OpenQA selenium)

At this moment I think it is enough, but in future I would like to have load tests, code metrics.

My question is what kind of steps I worth to have, what could you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tagging! Mark or publish code that's met certain criteria.

Automated reverting for failed commits ...

Alerting (emails).

Log publishing for debugging.

Premerge and postmerge jobs. This can help keep out bad commits in lieu of reverting.

fortify (static analysis), cobertura (coverage)

And whatever else that makes the quality of your branch/repo better.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend code coverage test, static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can add findbugs and checkstyle in your build step.

Findbugs will give you the potential bugs in the code (like memory lead, infinite loop etc).

checkstyle will enable styling guideline for your project/orgnization.